# Flutter - receive sharing intent, share PDF with iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, file, share, external

We are using the package [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) in our application, but with recent update of Flutter and the package not being updated for 15 months, the feature implemented does not work well now, **especially on iOS**, Android is still doing fine until now.

The feature: for every kind of document (PDF, txt, xls, ...) stored in the device or attached to a mail, when you share it with the application, it should open it, process it, and store it in our database.
So we use the package here to retrieve external data and open our application, and that both on Android and iOS.

We still have not found a workaround that lasts over time for this specific case. Let me know if you find a solution while I continue my research.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** A new package has been released, see [flutter_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sharing_intent).

Comment: Hello @T E, if the package is not updated since 15 months, you should probably contact the package owner and ask him if he is going to update it soon or not. If he doesn't answer or answers that he isn't going to, you should probably then fork the package and update it for use yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes this is what I was being thinking of, but I was wondering, this seems to be a feature that in my opinion could be used by a lot of people and seing a lot of issues in the package and not seing any workaround for it online is strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** A new package has been released, see [flutter_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sharing_intent).

I spent a few days on this error, finally I found the exact problem I was experiencing, and the solution.

I finally got the error for the .PDF file extension, the path is incorrect. There is a function in the **SwiftReceiveSharingIntentPlugin.swift** file inside the Flutter package [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) that is supposed to remove the substring **"file://"** at the beginning of the file path, but for some reason I still have it in my PDF file path, so it could never be found.

To solve this problem, I use the "*replaceAll*" method in my Flutter code:

```
file!.path.replaceAll("file://", "")
```

I updated the title of this post to match the problem I encountered.